# Android Studio consumes huge amount RAM

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, ram, android-studio-3.0

I have MacBook Pro 15 with 16 GB Ram. I am just running one project in AndroidStudio and it takes about 6 GB of RAM and make my MacBook slow. This is insane something is terribly wrong with AndroidStudio 3.0.

Please look at the screenshot it has two instances of java taking nearly 3.5 GB of RAM without emulator.

Is there a solution for this issue? I know about this https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#low_memory but I have 16 GB RAM it should take care of things smoothly without tweaks.

For some reason, Apple limited the RAM capacity of MacBook to 16 GB and Android consumes most of it which is making me frustrated because I can't upgrade the stupid RAM or fix Android Studio memory problem.

[image: AndroidStudio insane memory consumption for single project]

Comment: Android Studio consumes insane amounts of memory.

Comment: @MarkYisri I've had better results with IntelliJ plus the Android plugin. Android Studio is a fork of IntelliJ, so you aren't losing any features; whatever modifications Google made in the fork seem to cause a lot of headaches for a lot of people.

Comment: As a reference, AS 2.3.3 on windows is using only about 700MB RAM with a small test project open.

Comment: One of that Java instance is actually Gradle, try killing both Java so that you can free some memory.

Comment: I'm facing this problem and I am really considering to sell my Mac and use some hi-end gaming PC with something like a Threadripper CPU and 32GB of RAM

Comment: To hell to apple selling 16GB computers and saying it's high-end

Answer (score 1):

For ***MacOS***:

You can use *`ulimit`* buildin shell command to *limit the use of system-wide resources*

You can learn more about [ulimit command here](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)

For ***Windows***:
You can check [this](https://superuser.com/a/1263201/940117)

p.s: *Similar problem was discussed over* [here](https://superuser.com/questions/118465/how-can-i-limit-the-amount-of-ram-a-mac-os-application-can-use)